# What is the problem with my hanging basket? Am I overwatering or is it underwater

Tags: flowers, hanging-plant

I planted this hanging basket almost 2 weeks ago and it already looks like this. I’m not the best with planting flowers but I always do great with ferns. Everyone has always told me that I never water enough. I have watered these flowers every day and one day I fertilized using miracle grow. Someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and are these underwatered   or overwatered? [image]

Comment: What have your overnight temperatures outdoors been like since you planted this? How much sunlight does it receive?

Comment: If those are petunias, in the Southern Hemisphere their season has come to an end.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are overwatering. The soil in the picture looks rather waterlogged, and watering every day is quite often. Petunias do not like to stay permanently wet. Don't let the soil get bone dry, but do at least let it get dry to the touch between waterings.